# 0 frames on disk, cache is outdated : unable to reset multiple cloth physics cache

Tags: animation, baking, cloth-simulation

I have an animated character with 5 different meshes with cloth physics on it.

When I hit "Bake all dynamics", only one is baked in cache (the first one but I don't know if it is relevant to say it). All others have an outdated cache. If I hit "Delete Bake" on one of them, then hit "Bake" it only goes through the frames without calcutations, and the initial message remains : "0 frames on disk, cache is outdated". Then, if I render the animation, only the first cloth mesh (which is properly baked) displays as physics mesh...

Can you help me to reset this ?

Edit : Should I consider that Blender can't create a cache per cloth, so I have to export the first one (which is properly baked) in .mdd, then bake the second, export it etc ??

Comment: [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Hello i saw this post and i have a workaround. do 2 cloth sims at the same time by pressing "bake". and magically you have working cloth simulations again. it worked for me don't know if it will for you my guy.